# I18N C# Application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, localization, internationalization

I got a C# application, and I want to I18N it. I am using Visual Studio 2010.

I got some resource files, in several projects, they only contain texts.
For example:
  Project1
    Strings.resx
  Project2
    Strings.resx
  Project3
    Strings.resx

Lets say I want to have French translation, so each projects will have Strings.fr.resx.
I need to ask someone, who is not programmer and doesn't have VS, to do the translation.
How am I go about to do this?
Is there any tools (built-in or 3rd party) I can use?

For example, convert the resource files into some readable format, and convert back to resource files after translated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're in luck; .NET has extensive localization built in.  You can find the online documentation for it here: [Globalizing and Localizing .NET Framework Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6270d0z.aspx)

To answer the specific point about converting resource files into readable format, you may want to look at [Resgen.exe (Resource File Generator)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccec7sz1.aspx) which comes with visual studio or the windows sdk.